# Oracle Data Tools (ODT) - schema compare

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oracle, odt, schema-compare

We are wanting to source control our Oracle Schema - as we have a number of SQL Server databases on our estate we would like to use a common tool - for the SQL Server databases we use Visual Studio 2010 / dbpro which nicely source controls each object, integrates into our CI environment, and assists build/deploy to UAT and Live.

We would like to do the same for our Oracle databases however, from the tools on offer, they don't seem to be at all close to the functionality VS2010 provides - the VS2010 Toad plugin is no longer supported; we are trialing the ODT (Oracle Data Tools) plugin however I can't seem to locate how I can generate a delta script (compare) of an Oracle database project Vs a target Oracle instance - this seems to be a fairly fundamental requirement

Does anyone have any ideas ?  It might mean we may need to combine the source control capabilities of VS2010 with the compare (generate delta scripting) of another tool like SQL Developer.  Has anyone gone down this path ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this update in the [Oracle forums](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2551130):

Question:

> Hi,
>   how can i do a schema compare in Oracle Developer Tools for visual studio ? and is it possible to do compare through command line from ODT or by any other way?

Answer:

> This is now available in ODT 12.1 or later.
>   Here is a walkthrough:
>   http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=44785:24:1995235124222:::24:P24_CONTENT_ID%2CP24_PROD_SECTION_GRP_ID%2CP24_PREV_PAGE:8210%2C%2C24

**Edit:**

From my brief check, it enables comparison of existing schemas, but **not** comparison of the project with a database.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to compare tables in a schema (user) other than they one you are connecting as?  I cannot connect as the user I want to check, but I do have read-only permissions when I connect as myself.  I don't see an option to choose the schema.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it but redgate has schema control and source control for Oracle.
http://www.red-gate.com/products/oracle-development/

Comment: Thanks Pratik - the thing I like about the ODT plugin is that we all develop inside one IDE - VS2010 (since in our environment at least, there is an apetite to standardise for reasons of source control, CI, and deployment) - the Redgate product is standalone

Answer (score 1):

Oracle sell a Change Management pack and a Configuration Management pack , which they sell as chargeable extras to the Enterprise Edition licence.  Yes, that is two products.  Well not even multi-billionaires know where the next tropical island hideaway is coming from :)

Anyway, if your project has the spare cash you can find out more [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/oem/grid-control/overview/change-management-pack-11gr2-datash-131286.pdf) and [here](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/enterprise-manager/config-mgmt-overview-ds-068456.pdf).

Comment: Thanks APC, I guess it's not really in Oracle's interest to forward an MS product (especially for free) - still, the Enterprise Edition is worth a look